Positivity condition of an integral from two functions
The density operator $\hat{\rho}$ representation by means of symplectic tomogram $\mathcal{W}(X|\mu,\nu)$ (that is a probability density function (pdf) of the quadrature $X$) is the inverse Radon transform:
\begin{eqnarray}
    \hat{\rho}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \mathcal{W}(X|\mu,\nu) \exp{(i(X\hat{1}-\mu\hat{q}-\nu\hat{p}))}dXd\mu d\nu,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\hat{q}$, $\hat{p}$ are the position and momentum operators, respectively. The parameters  $\mu,\nu$ are some real numbers.
It is know that the density matrix operator must be positive semidefinite. Then $\langle \chi|\hat{\rho}|\chi\rangle\geq 0$, $\forall |\chi\rangle$. This gives the condition on the integral on the right-hand side to be nonnegative:
\begin{eqnarray}
    \frac{1}{2\pi}\int  \phi(1;\mu,\nu) \langle \chi|\exp{(i(-\mu\hat{q}-\nu\hat{p}))}|\chi\rangle d\mu d\nu \geq 0,
\end{eqnarray}
where the characteristic function of pdf is
\begin{eqnarray}
    \phi(1;\mu,\nu)\equiv \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{W}(X|\mu,\nu)e^{iX}dX,
\end{eqnarray}
and it known to be positive semidefinite function.
The question is, when the integral is nonnegative? Can we deduce some condition on $\phi(1;\mu,\nu)$?
We can see that $\phi(1;\mu,\nu)$ is independent from the choice of $|\chi\rangle$.
Thus I thought that looking at $\langle \chi|\exp{(-i\mu\hat{q})}\exp{(-i\nu\hat{p})}|\chi\rangle$ would give me hint on the integral itself.
I have an operator $\exp{(-i\mu\hat{q})}\exp{(-i\nu\hat{p})}$. I am interested in any conditions on  $\langle \chi|\exp{(-i\mu\hat{q})}\exp{(-i\nu\hat{p})}|\chi\rangle$, where  $|\chi\rangle$ is any state. My derivations are:
\begin{eqnarray}
    &&\langle \chi|\exp{(-i\mu\hat{q})}\exp{(-i\nu\hat{p})}|\chi\rangle\\
    &=&
   \iint dx' dx'' \langle \chi|x''\rangle\langle x''|\exp{(-i\mu\hat{q})}\exp{(-i\nu\hat{p})}|x'\rangle\langle x'|\chi\rangle \\
   &=&\iint dx' dx''\exp{(-i\mu x'')} \langle \chi|x''\rangle\langle x''|x'+\nu\rangle\langle x'|\chi\rangle \\
   &=&\iint dx' dx''\exp{(-i\mu x'')}\chi^{\star}(x'')\langle x''|x'\rangle\chi(x'-\nu)
   \\
   &=&\iint dx' dx''\exp{(-i\mu x'')}\chi^{\star}(x'')\delta( x''-x')\chi(x'-\nu)
   \\
   &=&\int dx\exp{(-i\mu x)}\chi^{\star}(x)\chi(x-\nu).
\end{eqnarray}
So we have
\begin{eqnarray}
F(\chi,\mu,\nu)\equiv \int dx\exp{(-i\mu x)}\chi^{\star}(x)\chi(x-\nu),
\end{eqnarray}
and the integral of interest:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \phi(1,\mu,\nu) F(\chi,\mu,\nu)d\mu d\nu
\end{eqnarray}
What are the conditions on $\phi(1,\mu,\nu)$ such that for any $\chi$ (and ofc $F(\chi,\mu,\nu)$) the latter integral would be nonnegative?

The same problem was already discussed (but not solved, see the comments on that post) in: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/37818/fourier-transform-of-the-product-of-two-wave-functions/37820?noredirect=1#comment50015_37820

I decided to write the whole problem and to address the mathematical comunity.

Yes, this falls into the class of difficult problems...
